# IndexedBD and localStorage undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, undefined, indexeddb

I have an indexedDB which im trying to use to capture form information on user registration. That part is working fine but the prof wants an account to be create once with the username and password set on creation so he can log in.

The way I approached this was with a localStorage API. I created a function to check if the admin account had ever been created, and if not to create it calling the addAdmin() function.

I tried to create addAdmin() by copying my addObject() but for some reason my db variable is returning as undefined in the console.

**Error" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'transaction' of undefined**

```
var mainForm, fName, lName, uName, pass, email, dob, phone, bio, nl, terms, school, gender, save, reset, db;




//-------------USER DB------------------//
function startDB(){
    mainForm = document.getElementById('mainFormSidebar');
    fname = document.getElementById('fName');
    lName = document.getElementById('lName');
    users = document.getElementById('uName');
    pass = document.getElementById('password');
    email = document.getElementById('email');
    dob = document.getElementById('dob');
    phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    bio = document.getElementById('bio');
    nl = document.getElementById('newsletter');
    terms = document.getElementById('terms');
    school = document.getElementById('school');
    gender = document.getElementsByName('gender');
    save = document.getElementById('save');
    reset = document.getElementById('reset'); 
    reset.addEventListener('click',clearForm);
    databox = document.getElementById('databox');

    mainForm.addEventListener('submit',addObject);

    //open DB
    var request = indexedDB.open('macroPlay'); 
    //if fails
    request.addEventListener('error', showerror); 
    //if succeeds
    request.addEventListener('success', start); 
    //if !exist, create.
    request.addEventListener('upgradeneeded', createdb); 

    //Create Admin account on launch
    chkAdmin();
}
function createdb(e){
    var datababase = e.target.result;
    var myusers = datababase.createObjectStore('users', {keyPath: 'userName'});
}
function start(e){
    db = e.target.result;


showUsers();// Show all values in the object store
}

function addObject(){
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to resgister?')){
        var fName = document.getElementById('fName').value;
        var lName = document.getElementById('lName').value;
        var userName = document.getElementById('uName').value;
        var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var dob = document.getElementById('dob').value;
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        var bio = document.getElementById('bio').value;
        var nl = document.getElementById('nl').value;
        var terms = document.getElementById('terms').value;
        var school = document.getElementById('school').value;

        //May need to set a loop to find value of radio
        var gender;
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('gender');

        for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].checked) {
                gender=radios[i].value;
            }
        }

        //set up transaction
        var mytransaction = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite"); 

        //get object store
        var myusers = mytransaction.objectStore('users'); 

        //Add item
        var request = myusers.add(new getUser(userName,fName,lName,pass,email,dob,phone,bio,nl,terms,school,gender));
    }

    // Show all results.
    mytransaction.addEventListener('complete', showUsers);  

    //Reset Form Fields
    resetForm();


}
function getUser(userName, fn, ln, pw, em, dob, tel, bio, nl,tm, scl, gender){
    this.userName = userName;
    this.fn = fn;
    this.ln = ln;
    this.pw = pw;
    this.em = em;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.tel = tel;
    this.bio = bio;
    this.nl = nl;
    this.tm = tm;
    this.scl = scl;
    this.gender = gender;
}
//------Create Admin Account-----//
function chkAdmin(){
    alert('before adding admin'); 
     if(localStorage.getItem('admin')!="added"){             
        alert('adding admin');
        addAdmin();
        alert('admin added');
    }
}
function addAdmin(){
    //set up transaction
        var mytransaction = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite"); 
    //get object store
        var myusers = mytransaction.objectStore('users'); 
        var request = myusers.add(new getUser('admin','Shawn','Smith-Choa','admin'));  
        request.addEventListener('success',showUsers);   
    //Locally store that admin as been created  
        var admin = 'admin'; 
        var value = 'added';
        newItem(admin,value); 
}

//-------------Web Storage API------------//
function newItem(id,style){
    localStorage.setItem(id,style);       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not assigning the value of `db` to anything so it's always undefined. I think you mean to be doing it in the `createdb` method, but really you should be capturing/assigning it in the `start` method which the `success` handler will trigger (I also can't find the `start` method anywhere)

Comment: "Not assigning the value of db to anything so it's always undefined." I don't understand why that's not a problem when they do the same thing in the createDB? I'll try running the chkAdmin() in the start() function, see if that  helps. I updated OP to include start